# Magento Reviews Form on custom page

Tags: php, magento

I have got the reviews form onto my custom page using my xml layout of my custom page. The custom page is in the my account section and displays all products ordered by the customer.

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="review/form" name="product.info.review_form" as="review_form" template="review/form.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

This puts the form on the bottom of my custom page, however I want to call the review form after displaying every product. I have tried the following:

```
 echo $this->getChild('review_form');
```

But it doesn't work, the other problem I will have is inserting the product ID into the form action. Am I going about this the wrong way?

UPDATE FULL CODE:

```
<?php
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

/* Get the customer data */
$customer       = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
/* Get the customer's email address */
$customer_email = $customer->getEmail();

}

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', array(
'like' => $customer_email
));



$uniuqProductSkus = array();

foreach ($collection as $order) { 

    $order_id = $order->getId(); 
    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id); 
    $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems(); 
        foreach ($ordered_items as $item) 
        { 
        if (in_array($item->getProduct()->getSku(), $uniuqProductSkus)) { 
        continue; 
        } else { 
            array_push($uniuqProductSkus, $item->getProduct()->getSku()); 

            $_product                 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
            $product_small_image_path = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200);
            $product_thumbnail_path   = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(150);
            $summaryData              = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->load($item->getProductId());


            echo "<li>";

            echo "<div class='previous-name'><p><a  style='color:black; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;' href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "'>";
            echo $item->getName() . "</a></p></div>";

            echo "<div class='previous-image'><a href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "'>";
            echo "<img src='" . $product_small_image_path . "' />";
            echo "</a></div>";

            echo "<div class='previous-rating'>";
            echo "<p><a  style='color:black; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;' href='" . $_product->getProductUrl() . "#product_tabs_review_tabbed'>Review this beer now</a></p>";

            echo $summaryData->getRatingSummary() . '% Would buy again <br/>';

            echo "<div class='rating-box' style='float:left;'>";
            echo "<div class='rating' style='width:" . $summaryData->getRatingSummary() . "%'></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='previous-clear'></div></div>";



            $productsreviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getProductCollection()->addCustomerFilter(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId())->setDateOrder();
            foreach ($productsreviews as $productsreview)
            {
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productsreview->getData('entity_pk_value')); 
            }

            echo $product->getRating();

            ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                    function toggle_visibility(id) {
                       var e = document.getElementById(id);
                       if(e.style.display == 'block')
                          e.style.display = 'none';
                       else
                          e.style.display = 'block';
                    }
                </script>



            <?php

            echo '<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'ajaxpro-notice-form' . $_product->getId().'\');" >Review Now</a>';

            echo "<div id='ajaxpro-notice-form" . $_product->getId()."' class='ajaxpro-form' style='display:none'>";
            echo '<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'ajaxpro-notice-form' . $_product->getId().'\');" class="btn-close ajaxpro-button" title="Remove This Item">Remove This Item</a>';
            $productId ='43';
            $this->getChild('review_form')->setData('productId', $productId);
            echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form', false);
            echo "</div>";

            /**echo "<div class='previous-button'>";
            echo '<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation(\'';
            echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
            echo '\')"><span><span>Order Again</span></span></button>';
            echo "</div>";**/

            ?>

            <?php $i = $_product->getId();?>

            <div class='previous-button'>

                <form action="<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>


                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>

                    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty<?php echo $i;?>" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="cartnum" />

                    <?php $qtyforaction = 'qty'.$i; ?>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
                    document.getElementById('buttonaddcart').innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="addtocartbutton" onclick="setLocation(\'' + url + 'qty/' + qty + '/\')"></button>';
                    </script>


                    <div id="buttonaddcart">

                        <button type="button" class="addtocartbutton button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>qty/')" >
                            <span><span>Order Again</span></span>
                        </button>

                    </div>          

                <?php else: ?>

                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>

                <?php endif; ?>

                </form>

            </div>


            <?php

            echo "<div class='previous-clear'></div>";

            echo "</li>";

    }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form');
```

Also if you want to retrieve the product id, it all depends on the way your custom page is loaded. I assume you are using a custom controller, it's the best place to use the register:

```
Mage::register('current_product', $product);
```

Then you can just call `Mage::registry('current_product')` in your template file.

Comment: I have tried echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form');  that doesn't work either?

Comment: As a note, you can remove the `template` definition in the XML you quoted. It's defined on the block level. Also you should have  `<reference name="content"><block type="mymodule/myblock" name="mymodule.myblock" template="mymodule/myblock.phtml"><block type="review/form" name="product.info.review_form" as="review_form" /></block></reference>` and call getChildHtml in mymodule/myblock.phtml - Hope it makes sense

Comment: Excellent thank you! The forms come through and fills in the line <form action="<?php echo $this->getAction() ?>" method="post" id="review-form"> with everything apart from the product ID?

Comment: Make sure your custom URL has the product ID defined under the "id" parameter. So `yourcontroller/youraction/id/productidhere`. Or replace `$this->getAction()` with `Mage::getUrl('review/product/post', array('id' => $productId));`

Comment: I have this bit of code in a php loop so im not sure now how I can get the unique product id every time? Currently it is blank?

Comment: I can't really tell you without looking at the code unfortunately

Comment: I have updated with full code, I had thought I could use ->setData('productId', $productId); ?